# Paypal Standard account and Developer API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, paypal

This might not be the best question for this site but does anyone know if you can use the developer api with a free standard account. I just do not want to code a bunch of stuff and not be able to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of **PayPal's** APIs can be used with the free account:

- **PayPal** Payments Standard (technically, there is an API available for generating buttons)
- Express Checkout
- Adaptive Payments, Adaptive Accounts, Permissions Service
- Back-office functions (refunds, delayed captures, etc.)
- Invoicing
- And probably more that I'm not thinking of

The main APIs that you're going to miss out on by not having a paid account are for ***PayPal Payments Pro*** (lets you process credit cards directly on your site) and ***PayPal Payments Advanced*** (lets you put a hosted payment page in an iframe on your site).  Pretty much everything else should be available to free accounts.