# API paypal i can use account standard?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I would like with a no business account, retrieve information about donations.

[Paypal Standard account and Developer API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597305/paypal-standard-account-and-developer-api)
true or false ?
I can't find a source on....
I hope that a part at the least of the API and open for non business account.

thant for read.

Answer (score 0):

For receiving payments, you should have either a 'Business' or at least a 'Premier' account which is available in some countries.

Do not use a 'Personal' account for payment processing.

If you don't have such an account, upgrade or create one now. There is no reason not to.

Comment: Hello this account only for get donation user app free.

Comment: i don't know what you are talking about, but the answer is simple. If you are receiving payments, use a Business or Premier account.  And if for some reason you have a strange advanced use case where you make API calls without receiving payments, you'll probably need a Business account for that arrangement.